# SQL many-to-many join and query old data record only

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I have 4 tables which have a relationship like the following

- `Brand` has many `Stores`
- `Store` has many `Brands`
- `Brand` has many `Transaction`
- `Transaction` belongs to `Brand`.

[image]

Most importantly, I have a concept called `mutual brand`. Basically is a group of brands that have the same store.

For example, Nike and Adidas both have store A and the store_id is `1`.

In the `BrandStore` table, we save

```
| bs_id | store_id | brand_id |
|   1   |    1     |     1    | <- (Nike)
|   1   |    1     |     2    | <- (Adidas)
```

Transaction

```
| t_id  | brand_id | created                |
|   1   |    1     | 2021-02-25 00:00:00    | <- (Nike)
|   1   |    1     | 2021-02-25 00:00:00    | <- (Nike)
```

The question is that, I want to query out all of the brands includes their mutual brand which doesn't have any transactions in the past 30 days.

For example, in the above example, no brand should be query out. Even `Adidas` doesn't have any transaction but its mutual brand does.

Here is the way to query out no recent transaction for a single brand, but I am stuck and don't know how to apply the many-to-many relationship.

```
select  b.*
from brand as b
where b.brand_id NOT IN (
    select t.brand_id
    from Transaction as t 
    where t.created_at >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
)
```

---

### Update

Assume we have 4 brands A,B,C,D

```
A and B are mutual brands
A and C are mutual brands
B and D are mutual brands
```

Example 1. a recent transaction associate with `A`.

- The query returns brand `D`, since B and C would be considered to have a transaction.

Example 2, a recent transaction associate with `B`.

- The query returns brand `C`, since A and D would be considered to have a transaction.

Example 3, a recent transaction associate with `C`.

- The query returns brand `B` and `D`, since A would be considered to have a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to list the brands that doesn't have any transaction based on Stores. This means you need to filter out all stores that contains the brand having transactions, then take the brands they have and return those brands in one query.

The following script will do what I just said:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM brand AS b
    ,brandstore AS bs
WHERE b.brand_id = bs.brand_id
  AND bs.store_id NOT IN (SELECT bs.store_id
                          FROM brandstore AS bs
                              ,Transaction AS t
                          WHERE br.brand_id = t.brand_id
                            AND t.created_at < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
                          )
```

If the above doesn't work, you might try with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM (SELECT b.*
      FROM brand AS b
          ,brandstore AS bs
      WHERE b.brand_id = bs.brand_id
        AND bs.store_id NOT IN (SELECT bs.store_id
                                FROM brandstore AS bs
                                    ,Transaction AS t
                                WHERE br.brand_id = t.brand_id
                                  AND t.created_at < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
                                )
     ) AS A
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't miss it. I don't know how to add it tho lol.

Comment: How did you select from multiple tables without joining?

Comment: @CodaChang you can't... unless you are referring to a union. Getting data from multiple tables using a join is essential basic SQL.

Comment: I know, but you didn't use `join`?

Comment: I didn't use `JOIN` or `UNION` but you can. Please test the code and see if works for you

Comment: It didn't work, I think you may misunderstand my requirement. This way won't query out the mutual store's transaction, but only the brand itself.

Comment: I've updated my question and give an example, would that help?

Comment: Could you please show an example of how you want the data to show? I mean as far as I understand, you need the brands to be queried that doesn't appear on the same store as the ones returned, right?

Comment: @CodaChang I updated my answer with my understanding of your question. Please test it, since I haven't tested it

Comment: I updated my question and give a couple of examples. I am actually not sure if you understand the same way..

Comment: @CodaChang my latest answer should fulfill the requirements, since a mutual brand relays on the Store_id. Please test the code and if you like, we can have a Chat and figure it out how can you accomplish that